# MVC 4 Http 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404, actionlink

I have a MVC4 web app deployed on a windows 2008 r2 box with IIS 7.5 I can log into the website but once I log in all of my actionlinks do not work anymore.

> Failed Request Tracing Error:
>
> ModuleName ManagedPipelineHandler  Notification 128
>   HttpStatus 404 HttpReason Not Found  HttpSubStatus 0  ErrorCode 0 
>   ConfigExceptionInfo Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
>   ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0)

My route.config:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Requirement", action ="Index", id= UrlParameter.Optional }
```

If anyone needs any more information please let me know.

Comment: Microsoft has made it very easy to troubleshoot the cause of a 404 "not found" error from the web server. read more instructions : http://blogs.iis.net/tomkmvp/troubleshooting-a-404

Comment: Make sure your modules section in system.webServer looks like `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`